# Using VBA to collect data with SNMP in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, snmp

I'm trying to create a script in VBA inside Excel to collect some data from switches. If the data is an integer or string, there is no problem but if the data is an OCTECT, I didn't find a way to translate well.

Here is my code:

```
Set objSNMP = CreateObject("OlePrn.OleSNMP")
objSNMP.Open "192.168.110.250", "public", 2, 1000
portsRBID = objSNMP.GetTree(".1.3.6.1.4.1.248.12.1.2.15.11.1.250")
```

Here is the result:

```
  : portsRBID(1,0) : "p" : Variant/String
  : portsRBID(1,1) : "€" : Variant/String
  : portsRBID(1,2) : "€" : Variant/String
  : portsRBID(1,3) : "€" : Variant/String
```

What is a better way to convert this?

This OID is a table, as you can see. If I change the `GetTree` to `GetAsByte`, the VBA returns an error:

[image]

If I specify the element in the table:

```
portsRBID = objSNMP.GetTree(".1.3.6.1.4.1.248.12.1.2.15.11.1.250**.0.3**")
```

another error comes up:

[image]